# Gradient Borders That Change Thickness

Tags: wpf, border, gradient

The gray borders of the inner panel with rounded corners in http://www.infragistics.com/uploadedImages/WhatsHot/VS2010/wpf-xam-trader-image.png appear to have a linear gradient *and* get thinner as they proceed out from the top left corner.

A linear gradient border is easy style in WPF – but how does one change border thickness as the border gets further from an origin point?